# Transactional replication - undistributed commands

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, transactional-replication

We have a problem in Transactional replication. The problem is that I have mismatch number of rows between the publisher and the subscription. We have Transactional replication in SQL2012 Enterprise edition SP3

- Publication – Standalone server
- Subscription – AlwaysOn server (Push)
- Distribution – 3<sup>rd</sup> server Standalone

The Publisher/Subscriber combination have several publication that all work fine except 1. The problematic publication has one table. The table has a column with XML  Data type, size – 260GB, 5.5 Millions rows.

The data  is not being replicated to the subscriber; Undistributed commands  show 919382 and counting. I think the problem probably in the distribution server.

The repl process try to exec  `sys.sp_MSget_repl_commands`;1 and wait for `PREEMPTIVE_OS_WAITFORSINGLEOBJEC`. I found that by using `sp_whoisactive`.

We get error message in distribution job:

> Raised events that occur when an agent’s reader thread waits longer than the agent's -messageinterval time. (By default, the time is 60 seconds.) If you notice State 2 events that are recorded for an agent, this indicates that the agent is taking a long time to write changes to the destination.

In addition there are no database locks. Please advise how to solve the problem. Thanks & Regards.

Comment: Damiano, it is a bit vicious comment and you are not giving advice on top of it. This is a first question for the user and you can understand him for formatting it too much, since there are lots of comments on formatting and phrasing.

Comment: Several questions: <br/>
Is it replicating slowly or not at all?<br/>
Are you seeing other errors in the replication monitor?<br/>
How much memory does the distributor have? <br/>
How are the drives configured? <br/>
What is the disk latency on the distributor for msdb and tempdb <br/>[(sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats)](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/how-to-examine-io-subsystem-latencies-from-within-sql-server/)

Comment: I just did some reading on that wait type and it can present when the process is waiting on a reply from a client. That is, it could be your subscriber agent that's causing the issue. Do you know what the value for CommitBatchSize and CommitBatchThreshold are for the distribution agent? Do you see commands being delivered (through profiler or something like that) at the subscriber?

Comment: The replication is not delivered commands, monitor show distributor to subscriber is pending. Server memory 64GB, Disks 64KB, CommitBatchSize  and CommitBatchThreshold are defaults values, AvgBPerRead 69771
AvgBPerWrite 12208
AvgBPerTransfer 66649

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enabling output logging on the distribution agent? That should tell you in detail exactly where the agent is getting held up.

[How to enable replication agents for logging to output files in SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/312292)